# Cannot see the specific line or file on Crashlytics - iOS - OBJ-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I'm not sure why Crashlytics didn't show me where is the line crash
i have follow all the integration instructions and read the documentation but still no result

and i'm sure that i've been upload the right dSYM file

its just showing me something like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqVbC.png)

and i've been looking around and they said to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POu8N.png)
but it doesn't help

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that happens with some bitcode enabled apps. It seems to be a bug with how Apple is regenerating dSYMs and we've (Fabric) submitted a report to them about it.

In the meantime, if you turn off bitcode and rebuild then you should be all set for future crashes.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion
i'll try to disable bitcode
but is it ok to disable bitcode forever 
i'm afraid it will causing something bad for the app on the future

Comment: We're hoping it gets resolved soon with the regenerated dSYMs.